# Capacity of two disks

Tags: pr.probability, potential-theory

Is there an explicit formula for the (logarithmic) capacity of a union of two disjoint disks? As far as I understand, one can assume without loss of generality that the disks have the same radii (otherwise apply a suitable Möbius transform etc.).

Comment: Ah, already found: it's in Theorem 4.2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01812

Comment: Hilbert-Courant, vol. 1 have the formula for the Green function of a ring. The formula you need is an easy consequence.